# Dijkstra APOC algorithm for all relation types

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neo4j-apoc

I have a question about apoc.algo.dijkstra algorithm. The general view of the function is:

```
 apoc.algo.dijkstra(startNode, endNode, 'KNOWS|<WORKS_WITH|IS_MANAGER_OF>', 
 'distance') YIELD path, weight
```

As parameters we have start node, end node, name of the relation and name of the cost function.

My question is, if I do have multiply types of relations and it is not feasible  to mention all of them, as I possible need to add additional ones. Is it possible to do something like:

```
 apoc.algo.dijkstra(startNode, endNode, *, 'distance') YIELD path, weight
```

Where * stands for all possible relation types. I already tried, but I am getting an empty response. My goal is to apply an algorithm to all possible relation types within particular DB instance.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass `null`  or `''` (Empty string) in place of `relationshipTypesAndDirections` and it will consider all possible types of relationships and directions.

Like:

```
CALL apoc.algo.dijkstra(startNode, endNode, '', 'distance') YIELD path, weight
```

OR

```
CALL apoc.algo.dijkstra(startNode, endNode, null, 'distance') YIELD path, weight
```